# Find the solution of $x''-x=f(t)$ using Heaviside Functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> Find the solution of $$x''-x=f(t), \ \ t\geq 0, \ \ x(0)=1, \ \ x'(0)=0,$$ where $$f(t)=\begin{cases} 
>       0 & 0\leq t\leq 1 \\
>       t-1 & t>1. \\ 
>    \end{cases}
> $$

First, I note that $f(t)$ can be re-written in terms of Heaviside functions: $f(t)=(t-1)H(t-1).$

Taking the Laplace transform of both sides:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}(x'')-\mathcal{L}(x)&=\mathcal{L}(f(t)) \\
s^2\mathcal{L}(x)-s-\mathcal{L}(x)&=\mathcal{L}((t-1)H(t-1)) \\
\mathcal{L}(x)&=\frac{\mathcal{L}((t-1)H(t-1))}{s^2-1}+\frac{s}{s^2-1}.
\end{align}
Using the Shifting Theorem, $$\mathcal{L}((t-1)H(t-1))=e^{-s}F(s)=\frac{e^{-s}}{s^2}.$$ Hence, 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}(x)&=\frac{e^{-s}}{s^2(s^2-1)}+\frac{s}{s^2-1} \\
x(t)&=\mathcal{L^{-1}}\left(\frac{e^{-s}}{s^2(s^2-1)}+\frac{s}{s^2-1} \right)\\
&=\cosh(t)+\mathcal{L^{-1}}\left(\frac{e^{-s}}{s^2(s^2-1)}\right).
\end{align}
The answer given is $x(t)=\cosh(t)+H(t-1)(1-t+\sinh(t-1))$. I do not know how the last term was determined.

Comment: Partial fractions on $$\frac{1}{s^{2}(s^{2}-1)}$$

Comment: @Mattos Okay, so now I have $$\mathcal{L^{-1}}\left(-\frac{e^{-s}}{s^2}+\frac{e^{-s}}{s^2-1}\right).$$ I still don't see how the answer is reached.

Comment: Proceeding from the result in the comment above, use linearity and shifting theorem noting that $\mathcal L^{-1}(1/s^2)=s$ and $\mathcal L^{-1}(1/(s^2-1))=\sinh(t)$

Comment: It should be pretty obvious? You already showed that $$\mathcal{L}((t-1)H(t-1)) = \frac{e^{-s}}{s^{2}}$$ so it stands to reason that $$-(t-1)H(t-1) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left( -\frac{e^{-s}}{s^{2}} \right)$$ You also have that $$\mathcal{L}(\sinh(at)) = \frac{a}{s^{2}-a^{2}} \implies \sinh(at) = \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left( \frac{a}{s^{2}-a^{2}} \right)$$ hence $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left( \frac{e^{-s}}{s^{2}-1} \right) = \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left( e^{-s} \cdot\frac{1}{s^{2}-1} \right) = \sinh(t)H(t-1)$$

Comment: Yep, thank you both for the help. Sorry I took a while for it to sink in, it was so obvious in the end (as like most things)